# How to resolve - ValueError: too many values to unpack in Python

Tags: python

'get_summary_csv' function will be called first which invokes the function 'methodname' and returning two outputs. I have handled an error if no data is there in the output list, return error message. When no data is there, instead of getting the error message, I get the Error.

```
def methodname():

    csv_summary_list = []
    header = [
        'Client ID',
        'Client Name',
        'Project ID',
        'Project Name']

    csv_summary_list.append(header)

    count = 0
    for result in csv_summary_list:
        count = count + 1

    # if there is no billing data available

    if count is 1:
        return {'message': 'No data available'}
    else:
        ID = int(csv_summary_list[1][0])

        return (csv_summary_list, ID)


def get_summary_csv():

    #Calling the mathodname() function
    (csv_summary_list, ID) = methodname()
    #Getting error here - ValueError: too many values to unpack 

    #Passing the output to call another function
    response = download_csv_summary(ID, csv_summary_list) 

    return response
```

Comment: A quick search shows well over 900 questions with the phrase "too many values to unpack" on this site. Have you looked at _any_ of those before asking this question?

Comment: Yes. I have searched. But I have not get relevant answer

Comment: which line is the error occuring?

Comment: (csv_summary_list, ID) = methodname()
    #Getting error here - ValueError: too many values to unpack

Answer (score 2):

Here `(csv_summary_list, ID) = methodname()` you're telling Python to expect two values from calling `methodname`. However, when `if count is 1` the function returns only one value, a dict `{'message': 'No data available'}`:

```
t = (1, 2)
a, b = t # a = 1, b = 2
t = {'this': 'breaks'}
a, b = t # raises ValueError
```

Try returning your error message as a tuple:

```
...
if count is 1:
    return ('message', 'No data available')
else:
    ID = int(csv_summary_list[1][0])

    return (csv_summary_list, ID)
...
csv_summary_list, ID = methodname()
# if count is 1
# csv_summary_list = 'message'
# ID = 'No data available'
```

Comment: Thanks!! I will try

Comment: Can I raise error and stop function once I get error as return {'message': 'No data available'} and not proceeding to next step

Comment: I'm not fully understanding your question: do you want to `raise` an exception with the message `'No data available'` or do you want to `return` the dict `{'message': 'No data available'}`. An exception will stop the execution, if you don't catch it, and the next step won't be run.